# Unmounting network file system on shutdown

Tags: networking, mount, shutdown, fstab, webdav

I am having a problem with the system hanging on shutdown for a minute or two. I started tracking it down, and I assume the reason is the following: I have a `davfs2` network mount in `/etc/fstab`, and this should be automatically unmounted at shutdown by `/etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh`. However, `davfs2` is not listed as one of the known network file systems (like `nfs`, `smbfs`, etc.) in this script, and although the script checks for the mount option `_netdev` (which is given in `/etc/fstab`), it does so in `/etc/mtab`, which is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts` and does not have the `_netdev` option listed. (See https://people.debian.org/~spaillard/Debian_Release_Notes/mtab.html for a short explanation.)

Obviously I can write my own little workaround with a custom shutdown script, but did anyone else come across this, or has some suggestion what to do, like file a bug against some package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either try adding `davfs2` to `/etc/init.d/unmountnfs.sh`, and, once you get it working submit a patch against `davfs2`, or

Try the workaround in the resource you linked to, "`For filesystems which do rely on _netdev for correct unmounting at shutdown, for example when using an NBD, a static mtab will be the only way to use _netdev in wheezy`" **May** apply, with the consequences listed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try working something out. There is a little bit of an issue as the file system listed in /etc/mtab is "fuse", not "davfs2", and "fuse" is not always a network file system. It seems that davfs2 used /var/mount/utab as a workaround instead of /etc/mtab to get user unmounting work at all. Also, the file unmountnfs.sh is part of package initscripts, not davfs2, so maybe the bug should be filed against that package, reading the info from utab instead of mtab.